# How can I determine if a subdirectory exists in C#?

Tags: c#, filesystems, .net, subdirectory

In C#, how can one determine if a subdirectory exists?

Is this neccesary when calling `CreateSubDirectory`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If the subdirectory already exists,
>   this method does nothing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8dtw1d6.aspx

Use `Directory.Exists` to check if it exists
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx

Comment: That page gives slightly contradictory statements about the method, though. In the exceptions table, for `IOException`, it says for the condition: "The subdirectory cannot be created. -or- A file or directory already has the name specified by path."

Answer (score 9):

```
if(System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path).Length>0)
{
//if this condition is true-->> Directory has sub-sirectories

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you need this?

```
if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
{
     // This path is a directory
     ProcessDirectory(path);
}
```

Comment: Wow, 2010 StackOverflow'ers were much more merciful.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`System.IO.Directory.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx). MSDN is your friend :)

Answer (score 1):

[System.IO.Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx)